# How to locate the figure at the current page?

Tags: floats

I am using `\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}`, which has a 2-column form.

My figure code is as follows:

```
\begin{figure*}[!t]
\centering
\subfloat[]{
    \includegraphics[width=.315\linewidth]{fig1.eps}
    \label{fig1}
}\hfill
\subfloat[]{
    \includegraphics[width=.315\linewidth]{fig2.eps}
    \label{fig2}
}\hfill
\subfloat[]{
    \includegraphics[width=.315\linewidth]{fig3.eps}
    \label{fig3}
}
\caption{blah-blah-blah.}
```

On the one hand, there is no problem when I use `\begin{figure}[!t]`.
However, on the other hand, when I use `\begin{figure!}[!t]`, the figure is always shown in the next page. I do not know why it happens. Is there a way that the figure is located as the same as `\begin{figure}[!t]`?

ps) The figure should appear across both columns. Hence, I cannot help using `*`.

Comment: `figure*` always comes the page after the position of the environment in the source, so simply move it earlier in the file.  Note you have removed the`p` option which means that the figure should go to the end of the document if it is large (slightly compensating by adding the `!` option, but that should only be used as a last resort in special situations)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356858/1090

Comment: It might be possible to automate the process, but it won't be easy.  The hard part will be putting it into the aux file.